# permissioned denied /users

Tags: permissions, root

Trying to create a directory under /users as root but get permission denied. Any idea why?

Thx
Dean

```
dean@dean-lnx:~$ sudo mkdir -p /users/testing
[sudo] password for dean: 
mkdir: cannot create directory /users/testing: Permission denied
dean@dean-lnx:~$ ls -al /users
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jun 28 00:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 28 00:51 ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Try running this instead:

```bash
sudo su
sudo mkdir -p /users/testing
```

If you are trying to add an account, you can just open User Accounts and add an account from there.

Comment: same error. This is what happens, I have both local users and nis users on this machine. NIS accounts have their home directory under /users. When I logged in using NIS account, ubuntu complains that no home directory can be found under /users/dean so I tried to create one as root and this error pops up......

Comment: Are you doing this on an NFS volume? You could be running into a policy called "root squash".

Comment: Look at [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/387111/sudo-make-install-permission-denied) for more help fixing your problem.

Comment: /users is on local disk.... another weird thing. when I "rm -rf" users as root, I get this error: rm: cannot remove '/users': Device or resource busy. But no one else is using that directory

Comment: I did a fuser -c /users and fount that /users is used by automount. that's why it cannot be removed. So I stand corrected. IT is NFS. But why did it work on my other ubuntu but not this one?? I am confused.... Let me look int root squash, I hope it's something fixable